# processing cost of assignment vs condition

Tags: javascript

The following questions rose up after a code review

```
function a (options) {
  if ( !options ) options = {};
  // other code dealing with default options
}
function b (options) {
  options = options || {};
  // other code dealing with default options
}
```

What is more cost efficient, a() or b() ?

Comment: Run a jsPerf test and see.

Comment: Define cost and precise ways to measure the "cost", please.

Comment: Be aware that this will be micro-optimization, if those two even have a difference. Don't start optimizing until you need to, always go with the more readable version first. This kind of difference will very very likely not matter in your app.

Comment: It came up after discussing code standard style.
"readable" is the key point.

Comment: There is nothing like "speed of language". It may run differently in different implementations (browsers). If you choose one way, another way may be faster next week (in a new browser release). There is no "microoptimization" for high-level languages such as JS. I recommend you to focus on algorithm complexity instead.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsperf.com/assignment-vs-processing

jsPerf said b() is fastest.
Thanks, I'll get back to my coffee

Comment: This probably differs between browsers

Comment: you are "creating" the function again and again in each test, instead of just calling the function.